# Most of the JS DOM methods and Properties not working on VS Code

Tags: javascript, dom

[image: Neither it is suggesting me keywords names and nothing is happening too!]
JS CODE:

```
for(var i=0;i<document.querySelectorAll(".drum").length;i++){
    Document.querySelectorAll(".drum")[i].addEventListener("click",drumButtonClick);
    function drumButtonClick(){
        // var drumSound=new Audio(".sounds/tom-1.mp3");
        // drumSound.play();
        alert("hello");
    }
}
```

I was expecting alert that says hello when i click any of the button.But nothing's happening..

Comment: Run it in a browser and check the dev console for errors. Hint: JS is case-sensitive, so `Document.querySelectorAll(...)` is invalid and should be `document.querySelectorAll(...)`.

Comment: I'm surprised there isn't a squiggle under `Document`.

Answer (score 1):

try to change:
**Document**.querySelectorAll(".drum")[i].addEventListener("click",drumButtonClick);
into this:
**document**.querySelectorAll(".drum")[i].addEventListener("click",drumButtonClick);

Comment: Don't post a real answer for simple typos. They should just be closed and deleted, and the answer slows down that process.